# MDX - How to count number of last member value

Tags: ssas, mdx

I've been struggling for quite a few days now on how to create a calculated member that would give me the number of time a member value appears in a set, but counting only the last value for a time interval. Here is an example of what I'm looking for:

Dimensions [Person].[Person-Name], [Time].[Year-Month] and [Result].[Result-Value]

Filtering time dimension from 2015-01 to 2015-04 for a non empty [Measures].[Intervention Count]

`John 2015-01  ResultA
John 2015-02  ResultA
John 2015-03  ResultB
Bill 2015-01  ResultB
Bill 2015-02  ResultB
Dana 2015-04  ResultC
Adam 2015-03  ResultA
Adam 2015-04  ResultA
Nina 2015-01  ResultA
Nina 2015-02  ResultA
Nina 2015-03  ResultA
Nina 2015-04  ResultA
Troy 2015-03  ResultC
Vera 2015-01  ResultC
Vera 2015-04  ResultB`

```
ResultA=2 (Adam 2015-04 + Nina 2015-04)
ResultB=3 (John 2015-03 + Bill 2015-02 + Vera 2015-04)
ResultC=1 (Dana 2015-04)
```

What would be the appropriate way of calculating this in MDX?

Hopefully someone can give me a query for getting the set and the measure I'm looking for.

Comment: Why doesn't ResultA include : `John 2015-02`? Is it supposed to be 3?

Comment: Answer the above and also share the query you have thus far.

Comment: @SouravA Thanks for commenting. **ResultA** for John is not supposed to be counted, since the last result in 2015-03 is **ResultB**, hence the "Last member for a time period" restriction I have. As for the query, I created this scenario to have a simple example, I don't have a working query yet.

Comment: @FrancoisB this seems to imply that you must have tried something?! `I've been struggling for quite a few days now...`